# Redirecting stdin and stdout to the same device in shell

Tags: bash, serial-port

I'm looking for a way to redirect stdin and stdout to the same character device. I know I can do it manually:

```
rz </dev/ttyUSB0 >/dev/ttyUSB0
```

However, it feels repetitive. On top of that, shellcheck complains:

> Make sure not to read and write the same file in the same pipeline

It's quite easy to redirect stdout and stderr to the same file (`cmd >file 2>&1`) but it won't work for stdin and stdout:

```
$ rz >/dev/ttyUSB0 <&1
rz waiting to receive.Retry 0: Got TIMEOUT
Retry 0: Got TIMEOUT
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to come with a solution that works in bash and dash but not in fish:

```
rz <>/dev/ttyUSB0 >&0
```

`<>` opens file in read-write mode. It is used as stdin. `>&0` redirects stdout to the file descriptor used by stdin.

Comment: Works in zsh and mksh as well. No one uses fish anyway

Comment: `ksh93` didn't error out on this, but when I tried  `cat <> /dev/pty/1 >&0` (another window's pty address) (WSL doesn't seem to have `rz` available, so I tried `cat`) it would only echo input on the terminal where the input had been typed. (Not clear what problem you are trying to solve with your O.P. (?) ).